# Does the torque on gear varies with different gear arrangements?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, gears, torque

Suppose that there is a gearbox with gear ratio 3000:3. The gear with 3000 rpm will have a smaller torque than the 3 rpm gear.

My question is that will for different gear arrangement(i.e planetary gear system, conventional gear system etc.)
is there anyway by which we can keep the torque of the 3000 rpm gear same but reduce the torque on the 3 rpm gear.

Comment: A hydraulic system could possibly give you that advantage.

Comment: Could you share, why you want to reduce the torque? I suspect that you have an electric motor of some kind and you want to reduce the rpms, but the problems is the strength of the gear teeth.

Comment: Why wouldnt you just slow down your motor and use less gears? Is there a particular reason you want to waste energy?

Comment: How will hydraulic system make any difference @Solar Mike

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I don't think that is possible no matter the arrangement.

If you measure the **torque** at the shafts (not the force on the gear teeth), then the power transmitted through the system should be (ignoring losses which for gears are in the order of less than 1-5%):

$$ P_{3000}= P_{3}$$

however, $P_{i} = M_{i}\cdot \omega_{i}$

$$M_{3000}\cdot \omega_{3000} = M_{3}\cdot \omega_{3}$$

$$M_{3000}= M_{3}\cdot \frac{\omega_{3}}{\omega_{3000} }=\frac{M_{3}}{1000 }$$

Having said the above, if you are just trying to **reduce the force on the gear teeth**, then yes it is possible. E.g. in the planetary system, it is possible to reduce the forces on the teeth based on the number of *planet* gears.

Comment: It is true you can build planetary system with more planets to reduce forces but having more then 2 makes it very very complex and rather impossibile to equally split forces among them. Some exists but no less then honing is required to have the system work in a satisfactory way.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly we have a gearbox aiming to reduce rotation speed, 3000 to 3 rpm.

For any gearbox, independent of the working principle(planetary, parallel axis, endless screw,...) the output torque can be computed quite easily. The output torque is the input one times the gear ratio. So in this case the output torque will be 1000 times the input one. That is the ideal formulation, in practice we should add a multiplying term called “efficiency”, always smaller then 1.

The gear ratio you aim for is quite high and having high efficiencies in those conditions is rather complex. If you aim to reduce torque to the final gear though this can be a good thing as it will be strongly reduced.

So the only thing you can do to reduce torque on the output gear is to decrease your efficiency(ie the opposite of what people always do), it will dissipate more energy as heat so good thermal stability might be an issue for your device.

In principle one could also discuss about gear tooth shape(straight one are less efficient then helicoidal ones, you might want to go for the former to decrease efficiency) or even more subtle characteristics of the gear such as addendum and dedendum but this implies having gears custom built which is not always a good thing.

Comment: Yes I understand your explanation but suppose a situation arises where a less torque is required on the low rpm gear then what one must do. Isn't there any way to achieve that?@Alberto Brambilla

Comment: The output torque is function of the input one so if you need less torque you can input less torque, ie using a less powerful engine. In any way you could put some numbers for a better understanding. If I understand correctly you want to use a motor(say 1Nm torque) and have at the final gear maybe 1000Nm instead of 3000Nm you would get theoretically, isn’t it?

Comment: What if you introduce an idler gear to mesh with a large load? Since power is conserved (less losses from efficiency), adding a heavy load to the idler would reduce power available for your output gear.

Comment: @jko yes that could be a good way of achieving the result he seems to aim for. An idle gear with a preload before the final gear could somehow decouple the system. At the end of the thing is a way of decreasing efficiency by losing energy somehow, in this case by rotating that idle gear. Be careful with thermal dissipation though because energy won’t be destroyed thus lost in heat

Comment: @jko could you please share any reference or example which will help me understand your mentioned idea

Comment: @ alberto Brambilla, regarding your comment about modifiying the addendum dedentum,  even if you did change the addendum and dedendum (to the expense of increasing the chances of undercutting), you would only manage to go to a ratio of $3000\pm1 : 3$. Isn't that right?

Comment: @NMech obviously the gear ratio won’t change by acting on addendum and dedendum, the 3000:3 ratio requested will be kept. One can change them in order to increase friction among gears and therefore decrease efficiency thus reducing the output torque keeping the initial one constant. These parameters are advanced ones so if one changes them randomly obviously one can do something wrong like undercutting but that can be avoided by good design

Comment: @Alberto Brambilla, out of curiosity, since you seem to have experience, what would you expect to be the maximum losses (compared to the typical 1-5%) if you utilised that design? Also, I expect that if you have significant power transmission (and therefore losses), then you would have to take care of the excess heat in the gear box.

Comment: @NMech In my experience losses with such high ratios are far higher then that. A lead screw design with a ratio 100:1 can have losses of more then that 45-50% rather easily. Parallel axis designs have higher efficiencies and maybe can get to that 5% you speak of but I don’t think lower that that is feasible in standard gearboxes. I cannot give any estimation on the addendum dedendum matter because too many variables are involved and not known to us, specifically power that would then change gear modulus.

Comment: Wouldnt it just ve asier to slow down the original motor with something like pwm or a vfd instead? And then use a smaller gearbox. Less energy to dissipate

Comment: @joojaa sure it would, as I pointed out in one of the comments the motor won’t give more torque then you request so even without a vfd you can still obtain the result. It all depends on what he wants to do since he doesn’t give any detail to discuss

Comment: Yeah thats true, but it could be a safety thing like the amp limit in a lab powersource. Maybe a clutch of some type?

Comment: He may simply use a torque limited joint for that, easy and simple. They usually work with two friction disks transferring the torque up to a certain limit after that the two disks can rotate freely

Comment: Yeah i have built ones with balls in a cavity that start to slip once the torque limit is exceeded.

Answer (score 0):

Another option you might want to consider is [worm drives/worm gears](https://khkgears.net/new/worm_gear.html). They typically have:

- High gear ratios (can easily go to 100:1)
- High losses

As a result you could get the gear ratio you want and also through the losses obtain a significantly less torque (at least 30 to 50%).

The main catch with the worm gears, is that if you transmit high power through the gear box, the temperature tends to rise up. As a result, the main difficulty is to design a system to efficiently remove the excess thermal energy.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my earlier comment, adding an idler gear with a load is one way to theoretically take power out of your system. I'm not sure if there are any real world applications of this since typically you just reduce your motor torque to reduce output torque.
[image]

You could add the idler load gear to any of the meshes that work for you. A simple way to add load would be to run a rotor in an electric motor as you're powering the motor to operate in the opposite direction. Essentially a magnetic brake.

Again you have to account for thermal dissipation but that's true in most gear trains.